# I have something wrong with picture in css

Tags: html, css

I have small problem with my picture in css. When I finished coding with DW and compiled it on MicrosoftEdge, it works and run normally.

After that, I post it into CODEPEN, but the picture in background and some content disappear, it seems that something is missing. I don't know why the picture disappears.

Comment: post the picture!

Comment: check your img src

Comment: Post the code if possible...

Comment: Post your html & css code and picture.

Comment: Post a link to the codepen and people will be able to tell you why pretty quickly

Comment: First Learn How to use HTML Tags .and how to use css .
i think this is off the topic ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload the image to the same path as the HTML you pasted into Code Pen. When you attach an image HTML for example...
`<img src="backgroung.jpg" alt="Background">` HTML checks its current path for the image. Since you changed the path, but forgot to include the image, there will be no image displayed.